# What is the difference between the Mobile web app and Desktop Browser web page environments in MobileFirst Platform?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

There are two environments that one can add to an IBM [MobileFirst Platform Foundation](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/) 6.3 project, Mobile web app and Desktop Browser web page:

[image]

The intended purpose is obvious - they can be used to add a mobile browser web page and a desktop browser web page respectively. As I understand it, the contents are hosted from the MobileFirst server itself and are accessed over HTTP(S) through a browser, unlike the mobile environments, which are hosted inside a hybrid container.

However, what is the actual technical difference between these two environments (if any)? Are they just names or do they actually do different things? For example, does one inject CSS that the other doesn't? The default hybrid resources (CSS/JS/HTML) generated when one adds both of these environments is essentially the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are indeed mostly the same.

Mobile Web is intended to be a "dedicated" environment for viewing in the mobile browser app of your smartphone/tablet.

Desktop browser is intended to be a "dedicated" environment for viewing in your desktop browser, or as a URL to be used in a Facebook app, or something you could embed as part of a webpage, ...

You could also create a Mobile Web environment and use Media Queries to cater for different screen sizes, etc.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, thank you. So *in theory* (I'm not recommending this!) I could swap them around and I would get basically the same results?